# In MVVMCross, is it possible to close a viewmodel and pass values back to the previous viewmodel in the navigation stack?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, mvvmcross

Consider the following example.  I have three view models, `ViewModel_A`, `ViewModel_B`, and `ViewModel_Values`.

I want to be able to navigate to `ViewModel_Values` from either `ViewModel_A` or `ViewModel_B`, select a value from `ViewModel_Values`, then return that value to the calling view model.

Is there a way of passing arguments to previous view models in the navigation stack so that I can simply call `ViewModel_Values.Close(this)`, thereby ensuring that the `ViewModels_Values` is decoupled from any other view models and can be used with arbitrary "parent" view models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing & using the MvxMessenger plugin is a great way to decouple view model communication in MvvmCross -

In your case, you could set up a new message -

```
public class ValuesChangedMessage : MvxMessage
{      
    public ValuesChangedMessage(object sender, int valuea, string valueb)
        : base(sender)
    {
        Valuea = valuea;
        Valueb = valueb;        
    }

    public int Valuea { get; private set; }
    public string Valueb { get; private set; }
}
```

In ViewModel_Values, you would act on / publish your UX changes with -

```
_mvxMessenger.Publish<ValuesChangedMessage>(new ValuesChangedMessage(this, 1, "boo!"));
```

And in ViewModel_A, ViewModel_B you would subscribe and act on them (as your ViewModel A / B would be still in the navigation stack when you pushed ViewModel_Values from them, so they could receive the message) -

```
private MvxSubscriptionToken _messageToken;              

_messageToken = _mvxMessenger.Subscribe<ValuesChangedMessage>(async message =>
        {
            // use message.Valuea etc ..
        });
```

More infos here -

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger?scroll=644
https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HQdvrWWzkIk

Comment: Even though this would work, this is not a very sustainable and safe way to implement what you want. MvvmCross support many other solution to do this, like @fmaccaroni mentions

Answer (score 11):

### **MvvmCross 5 onwards**

From MvvmCross 5 you can use the new `IMvxNavigationService` that allows you to have a much richer navigation. One of the new features is the possibility to await a value from another ViewModel after navigating to it and should be the approach to take after MvvmCross 5 instead of Messenger, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel_A : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public ViewModel_A(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var result = await _navigationService.Navigate<ViewModel_Values, MyObject, MyReturnObject>(new MyObject());
        //Do something with the result MyReturnObject that you get back
    }
}

public class ViewModel_Values : MvxViewModel<MyObject, MyReturnObject>
{
    private readonly IMvxNavigationService _navigationService;
    public ViewModel_Values(IMvxNavigationService navigation)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    public override void Prepare(MyObject parameter)
    {
        //Do anything before navigating to the view
        //Save the parameter to a property if you want to use it later
    }

    public override async Task Initialize()
    {
        //Do heavy work and data loading here
    }

    public async Task SomeMethodToClose()
    {
        // here you returned the value
        await _navigationService.Close(this, new MyReturnObject());
    }
}
```

More info [here](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/navigation?scroll=158#mvvmcross-5x-and-higher-navigation)
HIH

Comment: Is it possible to add more calls to the stack without return null to the first caller? Right now, in ViewModel_Values, if I navigate to another viewmodel, expecting a return value, it returns null to the first caller, so I cannot add more than one level.

Comment: There is an issue in the MvvmCross repository and there you can find the workaround, here the link https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/3184#issuecomment-439939567

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm going to try it :)

Comment: Problem here, if I go back using the default top/left navigation bar back button, the Close() is never called, and your `result` will never get any value. Actually, the await never returns.

Comment: it should return and `result` should be `null`. Which version of MvvmCross are you using and which platform?

Answer (score 4):

Use messaging center. Here is the sample code.

```
//for trigger
MessagingCenter.Send<object> (this, "Hi");

//put this where you want to receive your data
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case of trying to navigate in this pattern:

```
//pseudo code
"ModelA" => "ModelB<List<MyObject>>" => "ModelC<MyObject>"
```

OR

```
//pseudo code
"ModelA" => "ModelC<MyObject>"
```

I used the following work around in my ViewDestroy() override of ModelB<List>:

```
    private bool destroyView = true;
    public bool DestroyView
    {
        get => destroyView;

        set
        {
            destroyView = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => DestroyView);

        }

    }

    public override void ViewDestroy(bool viewFinishing)
    {
        viewFinishing = DestroyView;
        base.ViewDestroy(viewFinishing);
    }

    private async Task ModifySelectedObject()
    {
        DestroyView = false;
        MyObject obj = SelectedObject;
        MyObject modifiedObj = await _navigationService.Navigate<ModifySingleViewModel, MyObject, MyObject>(new MyObject());

        if (modifiedObj != null)
        {
            obj = modifiedObj;
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", "No changes made.", "OK");
        }
        DestroyView = true;
    }
```

This keeps the original

> "await _navigationService.Navigate<ModifyMultipleViewModel,
> List, List>(new MyObject);"

from **ModelA** open when navigating to **ModelC** from **ModelB**, but still allows the **ViewDestroy** Method to close otherwise.